# Is there a name for a group of value-related sliders?

Tags: gui-design, interface, wireframe, sliders, component

I need to illustrate a set of sliders.  Each slider can be moved up and down by the user.
Adjusting one slider will indirectly adjust the other sliders.
Is there a name for this kind of UI component?

The only example that comes to my mind is a music equalizer.  Although in my particular case, it has nothing to do with music.

I'm curious what approach I should take to illustrate this in a design document.

Comment: Would you also consider a RGB value selector to be an example?

Comment: @Jared Yes, that's a better example!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on this functionality on [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical).

The only difference from the default functionality is that you have multiple sliders.

You can also have range sliders (this is not described in the question).

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a **slider group**, myself, similar to how a group of radio buttons is a radio group.

For the record, sliders on a parametric EQ are almost never interrelated; raising or lowering one should have no effect on the others, it will just cut or emphasize that specific frequency.

As for illustrating it, you will either need good descriptions, good illustration, or an interactive example. You might start with one of these:

https://jsfiddle.net/b54dntrz/

http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/RsZYZ/

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical

http://jsfiddle.net/gthoma2/LYEHt/62/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question :

**Interdependent Sliders** or **Interdependent slider group**.

As to how to illustrate, here's a basic example:

You could add ranges,max min values,more sliders,colors, more complex relationships etc...

[image: Interdependent Sliders]

Answer (score 0):

I can find two names for this concept in fairly common usage online:

1. [Linked sliders](http://keith-wood.name/linkedsliders.html) seems to be a [fairly common](http://basecase.com/blog/linked-sliders-the-easy-solution-for-complicated-models) name for this
2. [Interconnected sliders](https://github.com/gburtini/jquery-interconnected-sliders)